# Does "git branch" list all the branches in a repository?

Tags: git

I am looking at the repository where I created a feature branch from the main branch and someone else merged my feature branch into the main branch.

The repository which I am looking at was first created by cloning a github repository and then pulled multiple times from the github repository.

I believe that there are other feature branches created by others.
But when I run `git branch`, it doesn't show the feature branches created by others. 
What might be the reason for that?

Thanks.

Comment: try `git branch -ra`

Comment: Thanks. what are those branches that are hidden by `git branch` but shown by `git branch -ra`? Why are they hidden by `git branch`?

Comment: Because they are not your local branches.

Comment: Aka, `git branch --help`

Comment: @Sergio Do you mean that `git branch` only shows my local branches? What are the different kinds of branches?

Comment: @Tim https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

Answer (score 2):

`git branch`, by default, lists only the branches available on the local repo. As mentioned in the comments, there are flags you can pass to it that will list other branches.

Where the comments get it kind of wrong, is suggesting the `-ra` flags together. This is actually redundant: `-r` will list remote tracking branches *only*, while `-a` will list *all* branches (local and remote).

And, in case you want to learn more, I'll [link to the man page for `git branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html). Happy reading!

Answer (score -1):

Try `Git branch -A` it shows all the branches that you have, and those you haven't downloaded yet from github